# Collapsable/expandable browser-style console for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

When I log an object in a browser console, I can expand/collapse keys which have 'large' (to display) values, eg, a key whose value is another object.

I'd like to be able to do the same for node. Eg, say I:

```
console.log(request)
```

...in an express app. Express 'request' items are large, and will easily scroll right off the screen. Being able to expand/collapse larger items would be super useful.

Is there an collapsing/expanding console for node.js?

Comment: ummm... logging in `node.js` goes to the terminal (`std.out`) in a text-format. have you seen collapsible output from `cat` or `ls`?

Comment: aah, I get it. You want a pimped-out REPL. No'pe, haven't seen one.

Comment: @rdey No to both questions. As stated, I would like an interactive console app. If you'renew to Unix, console apps like ls and cat are designed for scripting and hence non interactive, but there are many others, eg top and ls, that are interactive.

Comment: [console.group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_groups_in_the_console) i see somewhere what you searching, but i can't remember it right now. I also want to use it

Answer (score 2):

I've used interactive console apps (`top`, etc), and for me a REPL falls into that category. ;)

Here is a much improved REPL: https://github.com/Benvie/Node.js-Ultra-REPL

I don't think it allows you to collapse parts of an object, but this is in the works:

```
GUI-like interface with collapsable object views
```

It does provide `Toggling hiddens and builtins` at least.

Answer (score 1):

[node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) might be useful to you; it's not exactly what you seem to want, but it's capable of providing the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can log the object in the browser side console in which you can check property easily. [bonsole](https://github.com/Bert0324/bonsole), a simple way to log something in browser. Even in Linux, you can go to the LAN's ip to check it.